# Throws error when I use TimerTask method and WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In my code, I wanted to do, so that if the test takes more than 10 seconds, the selenium shows the title of the window and closes the window. This code is here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class SanDemoSearch{
    public static long czasStart;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        czasStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(czasStart);
        File file = new File("C:/automatyzacja/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.44.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl");
        Narzedzia.disableScreenSaver(driver);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lst-ib")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("resultStats")));
        WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.seleniumhq.org/']"));
        Assert.assertNotNull("Not found http://www.seleniumhq.org//",webElement);
        webElement.click();     
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys("test",Keys.ENTER);



    }


}
```

and:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Narzedzia extends SanDemoSearch{
    private static Timer screenSaverDisabler;

    public static void disableScreenSaver(final WebDriver driver){
        screenSaverDisabler = new Timer();
        screenSaverDisabler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            Robot r = null;
            {
                try {
                    r = new Robot();
                } catch (AWTException headlessEnvironmentException) {
                    screenSaverDisabler.cancel();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Point loc = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                r.mouseMove(loc.x + 1, loc.y);
                r.mouseMove(loc.x, loc.y);
                long czasEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(czasEnd);
                long difference = (czasEnd - SanDemoSearch.czasStart) / 1000;
                System.out.println("difference"+difference);
                if(difference > 10){
                    System.out.println("I can quit application");
                    driver.getTitle(); //exception: Error 404: Not Found
                    driver.close();
                }
                //if()


            }
        }, 0, 1*1000);
    }
}
```

When I run this code I got error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Error 404: Not Found
Not Found
Command duration or timeout: 49 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'SFL000361', ip: '192.168.1.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=10, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:32854/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 959f1633-48b4-4bb6-b24d-21a919747655
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getTitle(RemoteWebDriver.java:313)
    at Narzedzia$1.run(Narzedzia.java:35)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

and not always I got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session 4b141e0f-b680-4094-92f7-efaa6ea32e75 does not exist
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'SFL000361', ip: '192.168.1.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=10, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:28022/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 4b141e0f-b680-4094-92f7-efaa6ea32e75
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at SanDemoSearch.main(SanDemoSearch.java:48)
```

Problem is with line: driver.getTitle. Selenium didn't see driver?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Is_WebDriver_thread-safe?

> **Q: Is WebDriver thread-safe?**
>
> A: WebDriver is not thread-safe. Having said that, if you can
>   serialise access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a
>   reference in more than one thread. This is not advisable. You /can/ on
>   the other hand instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread.

Your code schedules a task using Timer object. Timer class uses another (background) thread to execute it's tasks - it means that two threads are trying to access the same WebDriver instance at the same time.
You can't use the same driver instance among two threads at the same time, because WebDriver is not thread-safe.

Comment: How can I add in my code new WebDriver instance and how to use properly two threads?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in java
:-

private static final ThreadLocal < WebDriver > webDriver = new ThreadLocal < WebDriver > () {
        @Override protected WebDriver initialValue() {
            return webdriver.instance;
        }
};